# Правильный подход к пагинации

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток, в каждом своем проекте строю пагинацию по новому, т.к. не нравится предыдущее решение, хочу получить дельный совет по правильному подходу к данному процессу.

Подход в к построению самой пагинации мне понятен, вопрос только в том как реализовать малыми нагрузками на БД?

`Данные:
- база данных, преимущественно mysql
- обработчик данных php`

Что делал в разных подходах:

1. Считал кол-во перед выводом данных и строил пагинацию, на понравилось из-за лишнего запроса.
2. Пробовал записывать данные в базе о кол-ве данных, не понравилось отсутствием  гибкости.
3. Пробовал загонять всю таблицу в память и работать далее динамически, естественно не подходит из-за размера данных.
4. Сейчас преимущественно при построении запроса использую `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ....`, и после построения запроса выполняю еще один запрос `SELECT FOUND_ROWS();` Это самое удобное решение на данные момент, но не нравится присутствие двух запросов.

**ps** Не нравится во всех этих подходах, что при предоставлению клиентам возможности сортировок, все слетает и приходится осуществлять повторные запросы. Кто как поборол это? Если не вы то остается разбирать чужие скрипты.

Comment: Из того что пишут и того что я проверял сам (mysql 5.5.58), первый вариант как раз и есть самый быстрый и оптимальный. В лишнем запросе нет ничего криминального (только если Вы не собираетесь между этими запросами закрывать соединение и открывать его заново). Четвертый вариант - проще всего, да, но он медленнее первого почти всегда. Скажем так, если правильно составить запрос для первого варианта - четвертый никогда его по скорости не превзойдет. А еще Вы забыли о пятом варианте: никакой пагинации. если результат меньше 1к записей, то стоит подумать и о таком.

Comment: :) меньше 1к? Мне на страницу вывести тысячу товаров, это не вариант. А по первому варианту, получится два полноценных запроса, 1 раз для подсчета, второй для выборки с и по, последний вариант уже совмещает в себе это. Но я еще раз почитаю, спасибо.

Comment: всё хорошо в четвертом варианте, вот только бы еще SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS не замедлял запрос. А так - всё хорошо. С другой стороны, если Вам это нужно только для одной таблицы и даже с SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS запрос отрабатывает "почти мгновенное" - так и оставьте так. Народная мудрость, не помню точно где увидел, да и дословно не помню, че-то типа "не пытайтесь оптимизировать то, что вызывается не так часто да и работает достаточно быстро".

Comment: Да нет, вы посеяли зерно и оно прорастает вернуться на `count(*)` и выполнять два запроса, у меня запросы очень часто JOIN'ят другие таблицы, и не одну, вот нашел теперь еще пару статей в которых народ спорит )

Comment: тут еще такой момент, что для count(*) Вы можете немного скорректировать запрос (но только с умом). Например, да, можно выкинуть большую часть JOIN-ов, чаще всего все.

Comment: Да это я понимаю, если эти джойны не участвуют в отборе. Я как бы не совсем профан. Но за беспокойство спасибо. Я почитаю статью одну там человек все доходчиво изъяснил, если переварю добавлю в ответ ссылкой, там букв много) Читаю.

Comment: Если учитывать привязку к контексту пользователя, то вы можете сохранять результаты (поверхностные, без соединений) в кэш пользователя со, скажем, циклическим буфером на 50 различных по типу последних поисков. А уже при выборе более детализированных дынных просто делать соединения по конкретной странице, зная ключи для связки.